# Syntax and escaping character error when appending a dynamic table row

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have a java spring-boot project and I am trying to append a whole table row with dynamic data in my ajax success call and need help with syntax. 
I tried escaping the - and /, but it is then throwing the following error:  EL1065E: unexpected escape character."

```js
$.each(caDocuments, function (key, entry) {
        $('#docTableBody').append($('<tr> <td>'+entry.storage +'</td> <td><a th:href="@{|/carrier-files/${'+ entry.carrierAppointment.parentCompanyCarrier+'\-'+ entry.carrierAppointment.id + '\/' entry.storage+'}|}"><i class="fa fa-download"/></a></td> </tr>'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do these all the time with cordova apps. It can be frustrating

```
  $('#conversation').append('<tr> <td>'+variable +'</td>' +
  <td><a th:href="@{|/carrier-files/${'+ variable +'\-'+ variable + ' +
  '\/' + variable +'}|}"><i class="fa fa-download"/></a></td> </tr>');
```

If you want to write it in one line you don't need the  '+ on the end of line 1 and 2.
You don't need the $ after the .append( and only one ) at the end of the code. You were also missing a + at the front of entry.storage
Good Luck, hope this helps and happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks @CJ Broersma . This was helpful. Then I realized I actually have to write a link that is outside site and variables in it. Any tips for that? Ex: <a th:href="@{| 'https://example.com/carrier-files/${'+variable+'}|}

Comment: Your welcome. I don't think you need the single quote before example.com  ... you only need to escape the actual variables. The double quotes after href= indicate that a string is coming.